# Unexpected margin and padding on bootstrap modal show with sticky-top class

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

When I open a **bootstrap** modal, I get unexpected side padding or side margin on some html tags.

#### One example:

Before showing the modal:

```html
<div id="fixedMenu" class="d-none container-fluid menu sticky-top px-0" style="">
    ...
</div>
```

After showing the modal:

```html
<div id="fixedMenu" class="d-none container-fluid menu sticky-top px-0" style="padding-right: 15px; margin-right: -15px;">
    ...
</div>
```

`padding-right: 15px; margin-right: -15px;` appeared in style property.

#### Another example:

Before showing the modal:

```html
<form class="sticky-top sticky-top-filters" id="filters" style="">
    ...
</form>
```

After model show:

```html
<form class="sticky-top sticky-top-filters" id="filters" style="padding-right: 39px; margin-right: -15px;">
    ...
</form>
```

`padding-right: 39px; margin-right: -15px;` appeared in style property.

What could explain such behavior from a bootstrap modal?

**UPDATE**

I just figured out that class **sticky-top** was causing the issue, when I remove it, problem desapears. (But I need this class)

Comment: Yep, I used to experience the same issue, and sometimes I used to overwrite it when it used to cause centering issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an anwser from this post:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27071

First, catch modal events to apply style:

```js
$('body').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.sticky-top').addClass("fixModal");
});
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.sticky-top').removeClass("fixModal");
});
```

Second add new classes in style:

```css
.fixModal {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```